# How to enforce LatLng bounds permanently

Tags: android, google-maps, camera, latitude-longitude

I have a LatLngBounds variable in my google map:

```
LatLngBounds QC = new LatLngBounds(
      new LatLng(14.656669, 120.998598), new LatLng(14.666965, 121.098934));
```

I want the camera to show only a particular city. I have implemented that it cannot zoom out very far, just zoom in.

```
map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {

                // adding marker

                if(arg0.zoom <12){

                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(QC.getCenter(), 12));
                }

            }
        });
```

However, if I don't change the zoom level below 12, I can still go to other countries in the map. Any ideas on how to enforce camera within the `LatLngBounds` ? Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the target in `CameraPosition arg0`.
Save the last known `CameraPosition` and then:
use `QC.contains(arg0.target)` to see if the target is in the bounds. if not. set the camera to the previous `CameraPosition`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried this `LatLngBounds bounds = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
           
              // adding marker
              
              if(arg0.zoom <12){
               
               map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(QC.getCenter(), 12));
              }
              
             if(bounds.getCenter() != QC.getCenter()){
              map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(QC.getCenter(), 12));
             }` but with this I can't zoom in anymore. any ideas?

Comment: What you've done in your code is: if the user moves, return to default position and zoom. you aren't allowing any controls.

Comment: can you give me an idea how to do it?

Comment: I did this `if(QC.contains(arg0.target)){
              
             }
             else map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(QC.getCenter(), 12));` I can just zoom in, just zoom in. I can't go to other parts within the `latlngbounds`